# How to use the CSV query language?

Tags: csv, jasper-reports

In JasperSoft Studio or iReport, how do you query on csv data? It has an option to do CSV query language but I cannot find any proper documentation or instructions on how it works.

I need to do group by and add conditional parameters without the need to transfer it first into a database.

Comment: [CSV Data Source](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/csvdatasource/index.html#csvdatasource) - sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JRCsvQueryExecuter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JRCsvQueryExecuter.html) lets you sort and filter data from a cvs file

The **sort command** can be done on single or multiple fields.

```
<sortField name="name"/>    
<sortField name="city" order="Descending"/>
```

The **filtering** is done by the `filterExpression`

```
<filterExpression><![CDATA[$P{IncludedStates}.contains($F{state}) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE]]></filterExpression>
```

You can not use a normal `sql` statement but with these 2 properties, you are fairly close to `order by` and `where`. Specially since jasper reports have build in support for `sum`, `avg` (through variables) and the `group by` through groups.

```
<group name="YourGroup">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldToGroupOn}]]></groupExpression>
   ...the group bands ..
</group>
```

You can find a full running sample in the jasper reports distribution under `demo\samples\csvdatasource\reports\CsvQueryExecuterReport.jrxml`, this is the [sample reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/csvdatasource/index.html)